# Random spaces when creating txt-File from PDF

Tags: python, nlp, pypdf

This is my code:

```
import PyPDF2

# open the pdf file
pdfFileObj = open('pdfFile.pdf', 'rb')

# creating a pdf reader object
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

# looping through all the pages of the pdf
for page in range(pdfReader.numPages):

    # creating a page object
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)

    # extracting text from page
    text = pageObj.extractText()

    # writing text to a txt file
    file = open('txtFile.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

# closing the pdf file object
pdfFileObj.close()
```

The problem is that i get "random" spaces when converting from pdf to txt.

**Question:**

**Why do i get these spaces when writing pdf to txt? Is it a problem of PyPDF2?**

An example of this is: "The apple is red."(PDF) and the text in the txt file is: "The **ap ple** is red."

[PDF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvVHw.png) to [txt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JZwC.png)

or another ex.:

[PDF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPLW.png) to [txt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNszc.png)

Furthermore, its not always inbetween the "apple". It could be from "Apple" to "A pple" or "Banana" to "Bana na", with no clear reason for these spaces.

I tried looking for recuring patterns, like always getting spaces between chars of a & p or others, but sometimes the same chars that get spaced apart, seem normal on other occasions.

FYI:

-The language i want to convert is German

-The pdf file is computer generated

Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: Could you add a link to a pdf file showing this issue?

Comment: You're expecting a PDF to understand about words, the way a word processor file does. A PDF just puts characters in a particular place on the page, and it is happenstance if the span of characters it places on the page corresponds to a word. The spaces you see just indicate that different bits of a word are in separate page description language instructions in the file. There is nothing that `PyPDF2` can do to reassemble those bits into a single word. The information needed to do that was lost when the PDF was created.

Comment: I just tried your script on https://fb2bookfree.com/uploads/files/2020-06/1592272906_stolz-und-vorurteil.pdf and that seems to work fine. You say that the pdf file is computer generated. How? Perhaps there something goes wrong

Comment: @EelcovanVliet by computer generated i mean "exported" by DOORS. Unfortunately i have no control over the exporting process and im not sure how they were created.

Comment: I dont know doors (I was expecting latex indeed), but perhaps you can upload the pdf somewhere and share the link. That may shed some light on the problem

Comment: @EelcovanVliet unfortunately this is a classified document that i cannot share, i will try to look for a similar file that i can share.

Comment: @KJ Could you please explain this again to me, i cannot comprehend this highly complex rocket science :)

Comment: Uchitel version of PyPDF2 do you use?

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 received lots of updates in 2022. It was also deprecated and moved to pypdf.

Update your code to use the latest version of pypdf. Then text extraction will work way better.